# Slow Measure/Visual when using SelectedValue

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a report that will allow my users to make selection based on the total of a column and date. So I created a table, one column, values are 1 to 20. Also a date selection, today plus 14 days back. Before when I asked to give me all devices with 4 or more outages or Date(2019,07,17), it loaded my visual within 20 seconds. Now that I'm using selectedvalue(), its taking my visual 9min and 54 seconds to load. What is the problem?

This takes 10mins

```
Repeat Devices Outage Count = 
var numberSelect = SELECTEDVALUE(Numbers[Numbers])
VAR datesSelection = SelectedValue(Date Selection[DateWoTime])
VAR devicesTotal =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Outages[Feeder_Device] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[DATE] >= datesSelection,
        VALUES ( Outages[Feeder_Device] )
    )
var caseTotal = CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Outages[CASE_ID] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[Feeder_Device] IN devicesTotal)
VAR devices =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Outages[Feeder_Device] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[DATE] >= datesSelection
    )
RETURN 
        SWITCH(TRUE(),
        caseTotal >= numberSelect,
        CALCULATE (
            COUNT ( Outages[DEVICE_ID] ),
            FILTER ( Outages, Outages[Feeder_Device] IN devices )
        ),
        BLANK()
    )
```

This takes 20 seconds or less.

```
Repeat Devices Outage Count = 
var numberSelect = 4
VAR datesSelection = Date(2019,07,17)
VAR devicesTotal =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Outages[Feeder_Device] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[DATE] >= datesSelection,
        VALUES ( Outages[Feeder_Device] )
    )
var caseTotal = CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Outages[CASE_ID] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[Feeder_Device] IN devicesTotal)
VAR devices =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Outages[Feeder_Device] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[DATE] >= datesSelection
    )
RETURN 
        SWITCH(TRUE(),
        caseTotal >= numberSelect,
        CALCULATE (
            COUNT ( Outages[DEVICE_ID] ),
            FILTER ( Outages, Outages[Feeder_Device] IN devices )
        ),
        BLANK()
    )
```

Why is selectedvalue() slowing my report down so much?

Comment: I just tested the SelectedValue(Date Selection[DateWoTime]), this does not slow down my report. So its only when I use SELECTEDVALUE(Numbers[Numbers]), can anyone tell me whats going on here.

Comment: Can you use Values instead of SelectedValue?

Comment: I just tried. I even tried max(number[number]). Still moving slow. I used and IF Statement and a Switch Statement. Even that doesn't matter.

Comment: Is there a such thing as a 'Having' Function in DAX? I would like to have something like Having caseTotal >= numberSelect. I believe its the 'IF' function that is slowing down my calculations.

Comment: how do you know it is selectedvalue?

Comment: I just know that I can put caseTotal = 3 and the data comes withing 10-20 seconds. When I change my slicer (which olds the numbers column) to 3, it takes 9 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've used something like [DAX STUDIO](https://www.sqlbi.com/tools/dax-studio/) to clock each element in the measure I wouldn't assume `SELECTEDVALUE()` is the culprit. I would start by eliminating unnecessary `FILTER` calls since these are essentially creating entire tables in memory upon execution (every time). Try this:

```
Repeat Devices Outage Count =
VAR numberSelect =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Numbers[Numbers] )
VAR datesSelection =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Date Selection'[DateWoTime] )
VAR devicesTotal =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Outages[Feeder_Device] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[DATE] >= datesSelection,
        VALUES ( Outages[Feeder_Device] )
    )
VAR caseTotal =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Outages[CASE_ID] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[Feeder_Device] IN devicesTotal
    )
VAR devices =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Outages[Feeder_Device] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[DATE] >= datesSelection
    )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        caseTotal >= numberSelect, 
        CALCULATE ( COUNT ( Outages[DEVICE_ID] )
        , Outages[Feeder_Device] IN devices ),
        BLANK ()
    )
```

Or this (which is equivalent just more readable):

```
Repeat Devices Outage Count =
VAR numberSelect =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Numbers[Numbers] )
VAR datesSelection =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Date Selection'[DateWoTime] )
VAR devicesTotal =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Outages[Feeder_Device] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[DATE] >= datesSelection,
        VALUES ( Outages[Feeder_Device] )
    )
VAR caseTotal =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Outages[CASE_ID] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[Feeder_Device]
            IN devicesTotal
    )
VAR devices =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Outages[Feeder_Device] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[DATE] >= datesSelection
    )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        caseTotal >= numberSelect, CALCULATE (
            COUNT ( Outages[DEVICE_ID] ),
            FILTER (
                ALL ( Outages[Feeder_Device] ),
                Outages[Feeder_Device]
                    IN devices
            )
        ),
        BLANK ()
    )
```

This article: [FILTER ARGUMENTS IN CALCULATE](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/filter-arguments-in-calculate/) goes over the dangers in using `FILTER` on entire tables.

Comment: I meant to message you after you sent this. I tried both of them and neither of them helped with the performance. I'm very new to DAX studio, is there something I can run with it, and post here to show whats eating up the time.

Comment: Well I'm glad you figured it out and although my adjustments didnt help, you should always try to adhere to those rules. This link has some examples https://www.sqlbi.com/tv/dax-optimization-examples/

Answer (score 0):

So I've adjusted my code and this works. This was the closest thing to a 'Having' function that I could think of. Now my report is running back to normal. I guess it wasn't the selected values, because "Outages[DATE] >= datesSelection" worked like it should have. So I'm assuming it had to do something with the 'IF' and 'Switch' function.

```
Repeat Devices Outage Count = 
var numberSelect = SELECTEDVALUE(Numbers[Numbers])
VAR datesSelection = SELECTEDVALUE('Date Selection'[Date])
VAR devicesTotal =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Outages[Feeder_Device] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[DATE] >= datesSelection,
        VALUES ( Outages[Feeder_Device] )
    )
var caseTotal = CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Outages[CASE_ID] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[Feeder_Device] IN devicesTotal)
VAR devices =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( Outages[Feeder_Device] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( Outages ),
        Outages[DATE] >= datesSelection
    )
RETURN 
       CALCULATE (
            COUNT ( Outages[DEVICE_ID] ),
            FILTER ( Outages, Outages[Feeder_Device] IN devices ),
            FILTER(Outages, caseTotal >= numberSelect)
        )
```